# How To Copy/Cut Row of Data Based on TRUE/FALSE Condition [Excel VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am looking to create a VBA that would copy all the rows that meet the condition of TRUE in the 'Product Price List' sheet and paste them into the 'Customer List' sheet.

Not all columns need to be copied, only columns A,B,C,D.

If more TRUE conditions are met at a later time, I require the 'Customer List' sheet to be cleared and re-pasted, to ensure continuity of Product Numbers.

['Product Price List Screenshot'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/649dw.png)

['Customer List' Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzZna.png)

I am a coding novice and have tried various attempts, to no avail. Please be kind :)
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code. Take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider.[Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/) or [Mid-Advanced Tutorials](http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/codes-examples-macros-how-tos-most-useful-basics-advanced/) and my [personal favorite](http://analystcave.com/excel-vba-tutorial/)

Comment: Maybe try to record the macro by do this manually : Filter the Product Price List column True/False into TRUE. Clear the cells of Customer List  from A5 to D whatever lastrow. Copy the filtered range then paste it to A5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Assuming:

- Your sheets are set up exactly as shown in your screenshots
- The values in `Column H` are true Boolean values (i.e. not text masquerading as Booleans)
- All existing data on `Customer List` will be cleared and replaced with the updated list of values associated with `TRUE`

---

### Macro Steps:

- Loop through the rows on `Price List`
- When `Column H` of the current row in loop is `TRUE` then:

  - Add values from the `Column A - Column D` to a `Union` which is referred to as `true_collection` in code
  - A `Union` is just a collection of cells. In this use case, it's used to create a non-continuous range to be copied/pasted

A more effecient way to do this would be to just filter your data set (`Column H = TRUE`) and then copy/paste the resultant (visible) cells of the filter. This is more-or-less how you would do this manually.

---

```
Sub free_code_come_get_your_free_code_free_code()

Dim pl As Worksheet: Set pl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Price List")
Dim cl As Worksheet: Set cl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customer List")

Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Dim true_collection As Range

lr = pl.Range("H" & pl.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 5 To lr
    If pl.Range("H" & i) Then
        If Not true_collection Is Nothing Then
            Set true_collection = Union(true_collection, pl.Range("A" & i).Resize(1, 4))
        Else
            Set true_collection = pl.Range("A" & i).Resize(1, 4)
        End If
    End If
Next i
            

If Not true_collection Is Nothing Then
    lr = cl.Range("A" & cl.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    cl.Range("A5:D" & lr).Clear
    
    true_collection.Copy
    cl.Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

End Sub
```